# Optional int parameter 'page' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type.

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I am developping a web application with spring boot and angular Js , i want to add pagination to my interface but it gives me the error mentioned in the title: Optional int parameter 'page' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

Here's my java Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getReports",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<DetailsReport> getTables(int page){
        return detailsReportRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,5));
    }
```

Here's my Js Controller

```
$scope.pageCourante=0;


        $scope.loadReports=function(){
            $http.get("/getReports?page="+$sope.pageCourante)
             .success(function(data){
                 $scope.reports=data;
                $scope.pages=new Array(data.totalPages) 

             });
        }
        $scope.gotoPage = function(p) {
            $scope.pageCourante = p;
            $scope.loadReports();
        }
```

And here's the html

```
<div class="container">
             <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class ="{active:$index==pageCourante} "  class="clickable"
                ng-repeat="p in pages track by $index"> <a
                ng-click="gotoPage($index)">{{$index}}</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Declare your parameter as `Integer` and check if it is `null` before using it.

Comment: It doesn't work i follow the course of my professor and he declares page as int and not integer  , i think the problem is not there !

Comment: Then send a page in your request. Is this a typo `$sope.pageCourante`?

Comment: the request works i test it with http://localhost:8080/getReports?page=0 for example  , the $scope.pageCourante is initialized at 0

Comment: Yes, the error happens when you don't provide a `page` value.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the @RequestParam annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getReports",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<DetailsReport> getTables(@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", required = false) int page){
        return detailsReportRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,5));
    }
```

You need to use the @RequestParam annotation to bind request parameters to a method parameter in your controller.